# MDX MAX operator resulting in 999/99999 querying on Dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, mdx, ssas-2008

The following MDX query for my dimension is returning values either 999/99999 depending on number of members in the dimension.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MaxKey] AS
   MAX(
     [Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].ALLMEMBERS
   , [Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)
 SELECT
   {[Measures].[MaxKey]} ON 0
 FROM
   [SPCube]
```

This gives me a result of 99999 though in actual I have values greater than this in my dimension and total count of members are 640,000.

Apply same logic to another dimension in the cube as follows:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MaxKey] AS
   MAX(
     [Sales Period].[Sales Period Id].ALLMEMBERS
   , [Sales Period].[Sales Period Id].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)
 SELECT
   {[Measures].[MaxKey]} ON 0
 FROM
   [SPCube]
```

The answer I obtain is 999 as the max value but the total members are of 675 of which I have Id's greater than 999.

I tried applying StrToValue function but then I get an error saying:

> An MDX Expression was expected. An empty expression was specified.

Answer (score 1):

Does this return something closer to what you expect?

```
 WITH 
   SET [X] AS {[Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].MEMBERS}
   MEMBER [Measures].[KeyMeasure] AS
     [Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY
   MEMBER [Measures].[MaxKey] AS
     MAX([X],[Measures].[KeyMeasure])
 SELECT
   [Measures].[MaxKey] ON 0
 FROM
   [dsvAfmsDWH_ServiceProviderCube]
```

Then you could amalgamate:

```
 WITH 
   SET [X] AS {[Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].MEMBERS}
   MEMBER [Measures].[MaxKey] AS
     MAX([X],[Fare Media].[Fare Media Id].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)
 SELECT
   [Measures].[MaxKey] ON 0
 FROM
   [dsvAfmsDWH_ServiceProviderCube]
```

The `set` X is worked out before the rest of the script so splitting it like this should help. Custom sets are always evaluated before custom measures so now the measure knows what set to play with.

---

Edit

As I cannot see your cube I have tested a little on `AdvWrks`

This is a simplified version of the error in your script:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[x]} ON 0
 ,[Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This returns the default member "All Customers" which I think will correspond to your 9999?

[image]

If I then expand to something like my first expression then we have this:

```
WITH 
  SET [s] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS 
  MEMBER [Measures].[KeyMeasure] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[maxX] AS 
    Max
    (
      [s]
     ,[Measures].[KeyMeasure]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[maxX] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Which returns a much better result, without the error that you added to comments.

[image]

If I then simplify to the equivalent of my second script I have the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [s] AS {[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS}
  MEMBER [Measures].[maxX] AS 
    Max
    (
      [s]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[maxX] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Again no problem with the result:

[image]

**Important**

What data type is the key property of the hierarchy `[Fare Media].[Fare Media Id]` ? If it is not numeric then `MAX` will not work.

Comment: Well I am getting the following error when I change that - The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The first query as I said, was giving an error that I listed above. The second one is again giving the 9999 as answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick turnaround. Well the data type of [Fare Media].[Fare Media Id] key property is BIGINT. I take it when you say key column you are referring to the KeyColumns value across that particular hierarchy property? Just confirming.

Comment: Coming to the new queries, I am again getting same 99999 as result.

Comment: @VKarthik I'm talking about the setting in analysis Services where the cube is created. I'm not talking about the datatype of a column in the relational database.

Comment: Would you mind telling me where exactly i would need to look for ? Is it in the BIDS or SSMS? Should I be looking at the Dimension object in the BIDS which is what I have posted here?

Comment: @VKarthik exactly - check in BIDS

Comment: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=6324BEB801DC478A&id=6324BEB801DC478A%21181&v=3) <br/>  This is my properties window. It is set to Regular, is that what you are asking me to set it to numeric?

Comment: @VKarthik I've tried my best to answer your question - if there is a problem with your cube please create a new question. Unfortunately I am not a cube designer or administrator but I do write `MDX` and have encountered problems with `MAX` before and it has been connected with the data type set in the cube ... I have had to then ask our dba to investigate.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot for your response. I will investigate on it from here on and try fiddling with the data type of the desired column. In my last response in the link I gave it redirects to Properties window screenshot of the Fare Media Id column, which is where I presumed the setting of numeric you were talking about, hence was only asking to confirm on it. Anyways thanks for the help again.

Comment: @VKarthik I don't really play around with the cubes in BIDS so can't help - I just get the feeling there is a data type issue.